# What is the equivalent of following query in Django python?

Tags: python, django

SELECT REPLACE(field1, pattern, `"<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + pattern + "</span>"` ), REPLACE(field2, pattern, `"<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + pattern + "</span>"`) FROM table_name WHERE field1 LIKE '%pattern%' OR field2 LIKE '%pattern%';

The following is my model. How can I code above sql in django python?

```
class news(models.Model):
    dbemail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dbsubject = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    dbdetail = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    dbimage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dbdatetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Email: " + self.dbemail + " | Subject: " + self.dbsubject + " | datetime: " + str(self.dbdatetime)
```

I want to query on dbsubject and dbdetail and replace a text with another text in the query and return the result.

This is what I did but it is not doing the job:

usernews = news.objects.filter(dbsubject__contains=search).order_by('-dbdatetime').values()

Comment: my teacher gave me the answer that I wrote it down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my teacher Rahim figured it out. Here is the answer:

```
        usernews = news.objects.filter(
        Q(dbsubject__contains=search) | Q(dbdetail__contains=search)
        ).annotate(
        newdbsubject=Replace('dbsubject', Value(search), Value("<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + search + "</span>")),
        newdbdetail=Replace('dbdetail', Value(search), Value("<span style='background-color:yellow'>" + search + "</span>"))
        ).order_by('-dbdatetime').values()
```